# Cannot access value in array using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve the previous data when the users click on the "previous button". However I am not able to retrieve the value in the array `data` using the variable `prev`. In other words **data[prev]** does not work. Can anyone advise how to do?

Javascript:

```
$("#canvas-item .previous-button").click(function(e){
  //Get id of which previous button(s) when clicked on. Ex: #PS, #VP,etc
  var prev = $(this).attr('id');  
  previous_content(prev);
});

function previous_content(prev){
  var project_id = $(" #info #project_id").text();
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action:'get_previous',
        prev:prev,
        project_id:project_id,
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(prev+"= button id");
        console.log(data[prev]);
        $("#canvas-item #" + prev + " #content-wrap #item-content").html(data[prev]);
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    })
}
```

The data array looks like this:

```
data['PS'] = 'mppp Lmmmm';
data['VP'] = 'Value';
data['C'] = 'Customers';
data['TT'] = 'Time';
```

PHP:

```
function get_previous()
{
  global $mydb;

  $project_id = $_POST['project_id'];
  $canvas = $mydb->get_results('SELECT * FROM canvases WHERE project_id=' . $_POST['project_id'] . ' ORDER BY date_submitted DESC limit 2');

    switch($_POST['prev']){

        case 'PS':
        $response['PS'] = $canvas[1]-> problem_statement;
        echo json_encode($response);
        break;

        case "VP":
        $response['VP'] = $canvas[1]-> value_proposition;
        echo json_encode($response);
        break;

        case "C":
        $response['C'] = $canvas[1]->customer; 
        echo json_encode($response);
        break;

        case "TT":
        $response['TT'] = $canvas[1]->target;
        echo json_encode($response);
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }

    wp_die();

}
add_action("wp_ajax_get_previous", "get_previous");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_previous", "get_previous");
```

Comment: You need to debug this a bit. Can you print out data first? function(data){
console.log(data);

Comment: That means `data[prev]` does not exist.

Comment: Isn't prev `undefined` when you pass it as parameter?

Comment: @wannadream. This is what it prints out in the console log when I click on one if the previous buttons: Object {ps: "mppp↵Lmmmm"}
ps
:
"mppp↵Lmmmm"

Comment: If it is already Object, no need to parse it again. Comment out 'var data = JSON.parse(data);'

Comment: The data array has 4 keys[PS, VP, C, TT] and values[mppp Lmmmm, Value, Customers, Time]. The variable prev is holding the id(PS, VP, C or TT) of which previous buttons is clicked on.  So when I do data[prev] it says undefined.@SebastiánPalma

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: I have added the php file. @Barmar

Comment: @ApplePie That's not helpful, we need to see the HTML that it generates, so we can tell if `$(this).attr('id')` is the correct way to get the ID you want.

Comment: I have tried it on my browser console log: jQuery("#canvas-item .previous-button").attr("id"). It gave me 'PS'. This means it works for $(this).attr('id'). @Barmar

Comment: Do the `console.log` messages show what you expect?

Comment: No, it shows undefined. @Barmar

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: console.log(data[prev]); shows "{"ps":"mppp\nLmmmm"}"